# How to generate an indicator value each tick, finance research, quantitive trading, vectorized backtest

Tags: python, finance, trading, indicator

I am working on a trading strategy where a bollinger band indicator needs to be calculated for each tick. The format, date - bid price - ask price.

My goal is to populate a column for each of the bollinger bands (low, mid, high), for each tick (row) in the dataframe so I can run further testing on my strategy.

From my research the steps to calculate the bollinger bands are:

1. Calculate the mean of the lookback window
2. Calculate the standard deviation
3. Upper band = mean + STD, Lower band = mean - STD, Mid band = mean

The bollinger band indicator uses a 20min lookback (20x1 min candles) window.

My question is: How do I calculate the indicator value for the lookback period. Do I calculate the mean of tick's bid prices, or do I need to resample the tick data to OHLC 1min candle data beforehand?

This is the code I have so far, without resampling.

```
#Parse ticks
df_t = pd.read_csv(r'EURUSD-2020_10_12-2020_10_12 tick.csv',parse_dates=True)
df_t.rename(columns={'time':'date'}, inplace=True)
df_t['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df_t['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df_t.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace=True)

#Create new columns for band values
df_t.insert(0, "upper_band", 0.0, True)
df_t.insert(0, "mid_band", 0.0, True)
df_t.insert(0, "lower_band", 0.0, True)

#Start iteration from the length of the indicator (start offset)
df_t = df_t [ (df_t['date'] >= df_t.iloc[0]['date'] + pd.Timedelta(20, unit='m')) ]

#Parse ticks
for i, row in df_t.iterrows():
    
    #Filter date range
    end_date = df_t.iloc[i]['date']

    start_date = end_date + pd.Timedelta(-20, unit='m')
    print('Start date = ' + str(start_date))
    print('End date = ' + str(end_date))

    mask = (df_t['date'] > start_date) & (df_t['date'] <= end_date)
    ticks_in_lookback_period = df_t[ mask ]['bid']

    mean = ticks_in_lookback_period.mean()
    std = ticks_in_lookback_period.std()

    df_t['upper_band'][i] = mean + std
    df_t['mid_band'][i] = mean
    df_t['lower_band'][i] = mean - std
```

Comment: What’s the actual question you have or error message you want to resolve?

Comment: The question is how to calculate the indicator value for the lookback period. Do I  calculate the mean of the bid prices in the tick data, or calculate the mean of the OHLC 1min close prices after resampling.

Comment: @Ghi, put the question IN your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing libraries. here's one: https://pypi.org/project/pandas-ta/

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage from pandas direct capabilities. For example, if you just want to calculate bollinger bands, you can try this:

```
df["mid_band"] = df.bid.rolling(20).mean()
df["upper"],df["lower"] = df.mid_band+df.mid_band.rolling(20).std(),df.mid_band-df.mid_band.rolling(20).std()
```

If you are using 1m candles, then I suggest that just resample your candles to 1 minute or just download the 1 minute candles. If you are using other aggregation type, then create your OHLC candles and run the code above.

Other things you might want to try and explore is existing libraries, like TA-LIB or the one mentioned by @Jonathan Leon.

BTW, to get the `end_date` parameter in your `iterrows` loop, why don't you use `row.date`?